# Turbo-flask turbo.push when button is submitted

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I am using WTForms and  turbo-flask
I have a template which I want to change

```html
<div>
{% if data is defined %}
    {% for item in data %}
        <div id="load" class="col-12 col-sm-6 offset-md-0 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 p-1 p-md-2">
            <div class="card rounded p-1 d-flex flex-column h-100">
                <div class="card-body p-1">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{item._source.judgment_name}}</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{item._source.justice_kind_name}}</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">{{item._source.court_name}}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">{{item._source.adjudication_date}}</p>
                    <a href="/court/{{  item._id}}" target="_blank" class="card-link">{{item._id}}</a>
                    <a href="#"  class="card-link">{{item._source.cause_num}}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</div>
```

And where I include it

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row px-2 pt-0">
            {% include "test.html" %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    form = SearchForm()
    if form.is_submitted():
        resp = es.search(index="test", query={"match_all": {}})
        data = resp['hits']['hits']
        turbo.push(turbo.replace(render_template("test.html", data=data), 'load'))
    else:
        return render_template('home.html', form=form)
```

When I use this script it doesn't want to work. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. Here working code

in app.route function

```
 if turbo.can_stream():
        return turbo.stream(
            turbo.replace(render_template('doc_cards.html', data=data), target='load_cards'))
    else:
        return render_template('home.html', form=search_form, data=data)
```

On page where content will be updated

```html
 <div class="container">
    {% with data=data %}
        {% include "doc_cards.html"%}
    {% endwith %}
</div>
```

and dynamic content

```html
<div id="load_cards" class="container">
    {% if data is defined %}
        {% for item in data %}
          .......
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```